# How can I sort my number list in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
list = ['c:8', 'c:9', 'c:13', 'c:19', 'c:2', 'c:3', 'c:0', 'c:1', 'c:6', 'c:7', 'c:4', 'c:5', 'c:14', 'c:18', 'c:17', 'c:12', 'c:15', 'c:11', 'c:10', 'c:16', 'c:20']
```

I used "sorted()" but get this result

```
['c:0', 'c:1', 'c:10', 'c:11', 'c:12', 'c:13', 'c:14', 'c:15', 'c:16', 'c:17', 'c:18', 'c:19', 'c:2', 'c:20', 'c:3', 'c:4', 'c:5', 'c:6', 'c:7', 'c:8', 'c:9']
```

But what I want is

```
['c:0', 'c:1', 'c:2', 'c:3', 'c:4', 'c:5', 'c:6', 'c:7', 'c:8', 'c:9', 'c:10', 'c:11', 'c:12', 'c:13', 'c:14', 'c:15', 'c:16', 'c:17', 'c:18', 'c:19','c:20']
```

Besides getting what I want, I want why `sorted()` could not work.

Comment: `sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x.split(':')[1]))`

Comment: `sorted` "doesn't work" because these aren't numbers, these are strings, so they're sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> l = ['c:8', 'c:9', 'c:13', 'c:19', 'c:2', 'c:3', 'c:0', 'c:1', 'c:6', 'c:7', 'c:4', 'c:5', 'c:14', 'c:18', 'c:17', 'c:12', 'c:15', 'c:11', 'c:10', 'c:16', 'c:20']
>>> l.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[2:])
>>> l
['c:0', 'c:1', 'c:2', 'c:3', 'c:4', 'c:5', 'c:6', 'c:7', 'c:8', 'c:9', 'c:10', 'c:11', 'c:12', 'c:13', 'c:14', 'c:15', 'c:16', 'c:17', 'c:18', 'c:19', 'c:20']
```

Because `'c:1', 'c:10', 'c:11'` are string, and `'c:1', 'c:10', 'c:11'` are all start with `c:1`. So you get something like `'c:1', 'c:10', 'c:11', 'c:12', 'c:13', 'c:14'`.

As my code, use key argument of [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) or [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort), and use slice to get the number, then use `int()` function covert the number into int.

Comment: Wouldn't ```lambda x: int(x[2:])``` be simpler?

Comment: @wnnmaw: Good idea, edited. Thanks :P

Answer (score 1):

use `sorted` with `lambda` such that `sort` on the number in `string`.

`sorted(list, key=lambda x:int(x.split(':')[-1]))`

```
['c:0',
 'c:1',
 'c:2',
 'c:3',
 'c:4',
 'c:5',
 'c:6',
 'c:7',
 'c:8',
 'c:9',
 'c:10',
 'c:11',
 'c:12',
 'c:13',
 'c:14',
 'c:15',
 'c:16',
 'c:17',
 'c:18',
 'c:19',
 'c:20']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need lambda function as key for sorting to split each element and convert second part to integer:

```
l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x.split(':')[1]))
```

Also you should rename `list` variable, because it is reserved name in python.